# modify wsdl port name or soap address location for an axis webservice

Tags: url, wsdl, apache-axis, endpoint

This issue is with axis2 webservice. The generated wsdl contains the below port and address details:

```
<wsdl:service name="ServiceName">
    <wsdl:port name="ServiceNameHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:ServiceNameSoap11Binding">
    <soap:address location="http://ipaddress/webServiceProject/services/ServiceName.ServiceNameHttpSoap11Endpoint/" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

My requirement is to edit the address location to something simple(with out having the ServiceNameHttpSoap11Endpoint) Is there any setting to customize the generated wsdl ? All I am doing is right click on the project in eclipse and selecting "create webservice".

Answer (score 0):

You can use your service endpoint as

```
http://ipaddress/webServiceProject/services/ServiceName
```

which is also right.But in wsdl,service endpoint ends with wsdl port..Both are right..